# Magento, do not link to SSL after being on SSL page

Tags: magento, ssl

I have a megamenu setup that link to categories under "Shop Now" at http://www.pondmarket.com/ and if I add a product to cart, and then go to cart (https page), and then link to one of the sub categories (not top level) it goes to an SSL page. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is this a programming-related question? Or are you simply trying to debug SSL?

Comment: have you created menu by your custom module ? As by default magento manage Secure and unsecure URL perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Check your secure and unsecure url in Magento Admin and also in core_config_data table in database.

Comment: Thank you for your questions and suggestions. I realize that my question was a bit vague. The menu is created by a custom module as part of the theme, and the menu options are chosen by selecting a category, so they are not hard coded. Tech9logy Creators, thank you, I am going to look into this.

Comment: Hi Peter, Write back to us, If this fix your issue or not.